# How to iterate through a key mapping and compare to another key mapping using functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have 2 key maps, that I would like to iterate over. If the key is the same, then I want to use `_.assign()` to override the values. For example:

```
var keyMap1 = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'egg'
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bacon'
  }
};

var keyMap2 = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 3
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 2
  }
};

// something like this, preferably with lodash 
var result = _.compareKeys(override, keyMap1, keyMap2);

function override(obj1, obj2){
   return _.assign(obj1, obj2)
}
console.log(result);
// => { 1: { id: 1, name: 'egg', quantity: 3 }, 2: { id: 2, name: 'bacon', quantity: 2 } };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your request, could you not just use `_.merge` to do both compare and assign?

```js
var keyMap1 = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'egg'
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bacon'
  }
};

var keyMap2 = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 3
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 2
  }
};

var result = _.merge({}, keyMap1, keyMap2);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```